# What's wrong with this COUNTIFS() formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Will someone please help me with the following formula

=COUNTIFS('CURRENT LEAD LISTING'!$C$2:$C$378,"ACT",'CURRENT LEAD LISTING'!$E$2:$E$378,"X",'CURRENT LEAD LISTING'!$A$2:$A$378,"<=&B$5",'CURRENT LEAD LISTING'!$A$2:$A$378,">=&B$4")

B4 is a date at the beginning of the week and B5 is a date at the end of the same week.

Once I can get this to work on a separate tab in the same worksheet, the bosses are hoping I can link to a separate worksheet in a different drive altogether.

Thank you so much.

Kellye Mac

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What is the problem with the formula? Is it returning an error? If so which one? Or is it returning the wrong result? If so, what is the right result? What do you want the formula to do? [Editing your question](http://superuser.com/posts/787667/edit) to include this information will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

For the last two criteria you need the range outside of the brackets so it "<=" & B$5 instead of "<=&B$5"

Final function

> =COUNTIFS('CURRENT LEAD LISTING'!$C$2:$C$378,"ACT",'CURRENT LEAD LISTING'!$E$2:$E$378,"X",'CURRENT LEAD LISTING'!$A$2:$A$378,"<="&B$5,'CURRENT LEAD LISTING'!$A$2:$A$378,">="&B$4)